# Custom Meta Box If Else Statement

Tags: php, loop, metabox, conditional-content

I have created a custom meta box for posts and I need to display said data. I have been using the below method to display the data, But I am in need of a slightly different solution.

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_box_text4', true ) ); ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_box_text3', true ) ); ?>" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
</a>
```

What I need is a way to do a IF/Else statement such is. If `my_meta_box_text3` exists `echo that`, else `echo this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<?php  
// get image source:
$metaboxtext3 = esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_box_text3', true ) );

// get link:
$metaboxtext4 = esc_attr( get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my_meta_box_text4', true ) );

// check if the image source exists:
if(strlen($metaboxtext3)>0){ ?>
   <a href="<?php echo $metaboxtext4; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $metaboxtext3; ?>" alt="" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/></a> 
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ok great ;-) (maybe you can mark it as answered)